# Does getting awarded your PhD in physics depend on the quality of university?

Tags: phd, thesis

Say you wrote a good thesis on some discovery you made in physics.

If it was a mediocre discovery, nothing special, are you more likely to get awarded the PhD at a 'not very good' university than at a top class university like Cambridge?

Comment: In part. But more so on the publication record.

Comment: It depends on your committee really. It is their discretion whether to let you get through with mediocre work irrespective of the "class" of the university.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The quality of the university and the quality of the theses produced are not perfectly correlated. You are just as likely to end up with a "nothing special" thesis at a Cambridge as at a Random State University. The criterion for awarding a PhD is the completion of an independent and original contribution to the field of knowledge one is studying. There is no requirement that it be "groundbreaking."

That said, given that the "top" universities also tend to have superior resources available to students, the likelihood that a "nothing special" thesis will be accepted *by the advisor* as suitable for a PhD thesis is also somewhat mitigated as a result.

Comment: *Just as likely*?  I don't believe that.

Comment: As someone who's been at a Cambridge-like school for my doctoral studies, I can attest that many of the theses do not exactly set the world on fire. Maybe I shouldn't have said "just" as likely, but the institution does not guarantee the quality of the thesis.

Comment: I also went to a Cambridge-like school for my doctoral studies and am now teaching at a state university.  The difference in the average quality of the theses is not hard to see.  Although the majority of theses at a top university are not ground-breaking, the percentage of ground-breaking theses at a top place is surely higher.  To say otherwise is to suggest that there really isn't that much difference between the students at a truly top institution and the 200th best institution, and I'm sure you know that is not the case.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: OK, your point is valid. However, with respect to the OP's question, the basic truth of the matter is that a "nothing special" thesis gets you a PhD at a school like Cambridge, too.

Comment: the range of theses at any institution open long enough is always the same; the distribution over that range is what changes from place to place.

Answer (score 0):

The quality of a thesis depends on several factors, the PhD student, the advisor and the work environment of the department where they work. th ePhD student should do the work and come up with own ideas and drive the work forward, more so towards the end than early on. the advisor, in most cases have established the basic research questions for the project in which the student works. The advisor also has a responsibility to facilitate understanding of the scientific method, ethics and plain knowledge to the student through the advisory role. The department may or may not have resources to provide a good work environment which includes size of collaborating research groups, lab space etc.

From this view it may be likely that a top tier university has more funding, has attracted "better" (however you wish to define that) scientists and lastly may attract better students (at least from the perspective of competitive application processes). It is, however, clear that these ingredients may not necessarily lead to success but it would not be a wide stretch of the imagination to say that basic conditions may be better and that this is reflected in the theses produced.

The bottom line, however, is that a good research environment is more likely to produce better work than just top tier ranking. In some cases bad luck may lead to poorer output, for example if the ice samples from Antarctica on which you completely rely for your work melt in a freezer accident. The question that remains is to what extent good research environments are determined by tier ranking.